# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404> in restful services

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to unit test my program below but getting error as: java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>

Test Class:

```
package com.hsbc.mvc;
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppContext.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

private MockMvc mvc;


@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).dispatchOptions(true).build();
}

@Test
public void testMyMvcController() throws Exception {

    this.mvc.perform(get("/newcontroller")).andExpect(status().isOk());

}}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController

public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("newcontroller")
public ModelAndView firstPage() {
    System.out.println(" Inside Hello Controller ....");
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}}
```

Comment: You may need a leading slash in @RequestMapping("newcontroller")

Comment: You used the wrong tag, use spring-boot instead of boot.

Comment: @mikep no not working with slash also

Comment: How do you start your application? Do you use external tomcat or embedded ? Maybe you have some prefix like `/yourApplication/newcontroller` ? Any security ? Maybe try with `@RequestMapping("newcontroller",  method = RequestMethod.GET))`

Comment: @lazarov I am using spring-boot to run the application so it takes tomcat internally. Also when I run it directly through web browser it works.. but for the unit test case its not working.
I also tried @RequestMapping("newcontroller", method = RequestMethod.GET)),this too is not working

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you should be looking for:

- Start your application with "--debug" or if you are using Log4J / Logback activate DEBUG logs, and look in the logs for the registration of your RestController.
- Check your application.properties or application.yml for `server.servlet-path`  and `server.context-path`.
- If you have a web.xml check for the servlet mapping of the Spring DispatcherServlet.